# jQuery: count TDs with same background color

Tags: jquery, css, background-color

I am pretty new to jQuery and am looking for a way to count all TDs in one table that have the same background color.

The corresponding TDs do not have a class for the background but look as follows as this is set programmatically in the code before (all other TDs have transparent background).

```
<td class="clickable search " style="background-color: yellow;">some value</td>
```

I tried the following but this always returns 0:

```
alert($("td[style='background-color: yellow']").length);
```

Thanks for any help, Mike.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to loop through all the TDs and check the background color.

Using [grep](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/)

```
alert(
    $.grep($('td'),function(TD){
       return $(TD).css('background-color') == 'rgb(255, 255, 0)';
    }).length
);
```

Or [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) which is better for DOM elements

```
alert(
    $('td').filter(function(){
    return $(this).css('background-color') == 'rgb(255, 255, 0)';
}).length
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to get all td's and then use [jQuery Filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to check if it's got the background color of yellow or not.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6Yfk4/)

```
var yellows = $('td').filter(function(){
    return $(this).css('background-color') === 'rgb(255, 255, 0)';
}).length;
```

Comment: Thanks. This returns [object Object] and if I add length then it returns 0